# How to access google chrome extension from any page's javascript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to figure out how can I call into my extension from a normal web page. 
All documentation that I find seems to be either for communication between extensions, or between content scripts and extensions.

Any pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should make a content script, that injects an object into your page that calls your extension.

Create a content script that injects YourExt.js into every page, which should contain:

```
var YourExt = {
doThis: function () {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest('doThis');
},
doThat: function () {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({
        action: 'doThat',
        params: ['foo','bar']
    });
}
}
```

Comment: this looks like the simplest solution, tnx!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how the above should get injected, and how to call it from the page it was injected into?

Comment: I second @apenwarr, this is a bit enigmatic and could be explained in a more complete and full context

Answer (score 1):

While extensions can't access page variables and vice versa, you can communicate between page and extension through events. Here is a quick example of creating custom events:

```
function fireEvent(name, target) {
    //Ready: create a generic event
    var evt = document.createEvent("Events")
    //Aim: initialize it to be the event we want
    evt.initEvent(name, true, true); //true for can bubble, true for cancelable
    //FIRE!
    target.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

function foobar() {
    alert("foobar");
}

function testEvents() {
    window.addEventListener("foobar", foobar, false); //false to get it in bubble not capture.
    fireEvent("foobar", document);
}
```

(taken from [here](http://the.unwashedmeme.com/blog/2004/10/04/custom-javascript-events/))

So if you need to pass information from a page to an extension, you would need to fire a custom event on a page which you will be listening to in your content script.

Comment: Note also that you can create a "CustomEvent" and give it arbitrary data as the "detail". http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-CustomEvent