# Creating webplugins

Tags: c#, java, google-chrome, plugins

I am trying to create a program that will be passed input data from events a user fires from a webpage on their browser. I am aiming at google-chrome currently with the program being in either java or C#. I know this is possible because Spotify does this, so does the Battlefield 3 PC gui. How can I go about doing this? Does the user need to install an extension or can I get that information straight from google-chrome? Note: The webpage is not being run on localhost.

Comment: Here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637185/how-to-access-google-chrome-extension-from-any-pages-javascript

Comment: That still keeps the information contained in the browser. I need to pass it to a desktop application.

Comment: I have not worked with spotify, but my humble guess is that they have a URI-listener registered in the browser which launches spotify. If this is not the case would you care to explain how/what exactly spotify does? (How it seems to work, etc.)

Comment: Also you could write a java applet which asks for elevated security privileges and passes the input data from the "webpage" into a local program via sockets or another IPC mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to look into web sockets. Web sockets are just cool. I got a huge grin on my face the first time I got demo working. :D

Here's a tutorial that helped me out:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143158/an-introduction-to-websockets/

You can create a socket listen in your appilcation then connect to it from javascript, passing whatever data you desire. It's nicer then ajax as it's a persistent open connection and you don't have the overhead of http calls.